# enable default context menu in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, webdriver, internet-explorer-11

Using IE11,  I try to view a specific element on a webpage using  "context menu"-> "Inspect element" , however on a specific webpage, "inspect element" is not accessible because the webpage has replaced the default IE11 context menu with a custom context menu.

How can I still gain access to "inspect element"from IE ?

Comment: Click right button on that page and find the "inspect element" tab.Enjoy!!

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud: The question explicitly states that the default context menu has been replaced and is therefore inaccessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing `F12` will open IE's developer tools. There, in the `DOM Explorer` tab, you will find the `select element` button, which allows you to inspect the element you click on.

[image]